# Using Where Clause in a Union Query

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query like this

```
SELECT id, dpost FROM uid1088_qposts
UNION
SELECT id, dpost FROM uid1091_qposts
WHERE DATE(dpost)='2012-01-01'
```

but the dpost column is a datetime column which stores a data like this

> 2012-01-12 11:55:43

the query shows no errors but produces a wrong output

[image: its a query done in phpMyAdmin]

is there anyway i can union two tables using a where clause in this kind of filtering?
the two tables does not unite... only the first queried table shows its data and filters a wrong date

Comment: please make your question clearer. what's the output you are looking for?

Comment: I want to do a mysql query like that... i have two tables to unite and use a where clause by using a date against the dpost column. but the dpost column is datetime column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case your code is interpreted like :

```
(SELECT id, dpost FROM uid1088_qposts)
UNION
(SELECT id, dpost FROM uid1091_qposts WHERE DATE(dpost)='2012-01-01')
```

if you want to filter all of your lines use

```
(SELECT id, dpost FROM uid1088_qposts WHERE DATE(dpost)='2012-01-01')
UNION
(SELECT id, dpost FROM uid1091_qposts WHERE DATE(dpost)='2012-01-01')
```

Answer (score 9):

In this case you can use a subquery -

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id, dpost FROM uid1088_qposts
    UNION
  SELECT id, dpost FROM uid1091_qposts
  ) t
WHERE DATE(dpost)='2012-01-01';
```

Comment: Isn't it a lot less efficient than applying the condition **before** making the `UNION`?

Comment: @Tadeck Yes, this way is less efficient, especially on big tables.

Comment: I like this solution because it makes elegant code. Processor time is cheap, developer time is expensive :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to limit the results from both tables, then put `WHERE` clause in both queries.

`UNION` just appends the results from one query to the results of another one.

Answer (score 1):

The `WHERE` clause in your code only applies to the second query in the union, not both. To apply it to both you'll need to use it with both:

```
SELECT id, dpost FROM uid1088_qposts
  WHERE DATE(dpost) = '2012-01-01'
UNION
SELECT id, dpost FROM uid1091_qposts
  WHERE DATE(dpost) = '2012-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AllRecords.`ID`, AllRecords.`dPost`
    (SELECT `ID`, `dPost` FROM uid1088_qposts
        UNION
    SELECT `ID`, `dPost` FROM uid1091_qposts) as AllRecords
FROM AllRecords
WHERE DATE(dpost)='2012-01-01';
```